# Gnome Control Center bug/forcing return on user screen

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-control-center

I can't find the answer to my question on the net, so I'll ask it here. 
I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, GNOME, and since a recent update I can't access the Control Center of Gnome. When I click on the icon, I have a black screen and a return to the user screen (where I can choose a user session). From there, I type my password and I can return to the desktop but all my applications will have been closed. Same with the terminal via gnome-control-center.

At the end of this bug report, Chris Wakeman details the same problem as mine : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1755536. But I can't find any answer on his question not on this website or elsewhere.

I've already tried to:

- uninstall and reinstall Control Center,
- update/upgrade Control Center,
- because I have a nvida video card, I suspected a Driver problem; I tested several of them (proprietary and open source),

but without success...

If anyone has ever had an equivalent problem, I'm all about finding solutions! 
Thanks !

Comment: I've just discover the same problem when I launch the "Help" app !

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution ; for those facing the same problem, I post below what worked for me.

I think it was indeed a driver issue for my nvidia graphics card ; the Open Source drivers were no longer in line with the most recent update of Ubuntu 18.04.
In the update manager, tab Additional drivers, I used the nvidia 440 drivers (the most stable normally) **and** I also activated the *updates in anticipation* (bionic-proposed) in the Development options tab.

Hopefully this will help someone.